# Why is the word "cast" used to handle async message in a GenServer?

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp, gen-server

Why, in Erlang/Elixir, is the asynchronous `GenServer` handler named with `handle_cast`? The `handle_` part is obvious, but why the word *cast*?

The only thing I can think of is that it is akin to just throwing something out there (as in *cast*ing a net) vs *call*ing out for something and waiting for a reply.

Comment: It might come from networking terminology, like broadcast, unicast, multicast, anycast, etc. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcasting_(networking))

Comment: @MikeBuhot Ah, I hadn't thought about that angle. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeBuhot Good perspective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you answered the question yourself, already.

> The only thing I can think of is that it is akin to just throwing something out there (as in casting a net) vs calling out for something and waiting for a reply.

However, apart from asking the erlang creators, we can only speculate.

[**`Cast`**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cast): `to cause to move or send forth by throwing`

Basically, you're *tossing* a message to the GenServer, not expecting something in response.

[**`Call`**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/call): `to make a request or demand`

I think this is something that expects a response. If you call to someone you expect them to answer.

Comment: Yep. That's about the size of it.